# XamlParerException: while trying to link text to Xaml page

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

(Windows Phone Project ) I am trying to create a scenario were a user would click a text and a xaml page would be displayed be display. 
The text is  called  "Terms and Condition".

```
Event code for the text component
 private void MouseEnter_Agent(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AgentTerms.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

The Xaml interface code

```
 <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="30" Foreground="Red"  MouseEnter="MouseEnter_Agent">
                    <Underline>
                        <Run Text="Read JizAgent Terms and Conditions"/>
                    </Underline>
                    <LineBreak/>
                    <Run/>
                </TextBlock>
```

I get the error when I click the text - XamlParerException

Comment: Which implementation of XAML (e.g. WPF, WinRT XAML) are you using?

Comment: It for windows Phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong `EventArgs` class in your event handler's signature. You should be using `MouseEventArgs`. Take this basic example:

```
<Window x:Class="MouseEventArgs.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MouseEventArgs" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="Green"
          MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter" />
</Window>
```

**Code behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MouseEventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Grid_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
```

If this fails then it would have to be an issue with the markup in `AgentTerms.xaml`.

Comment: `TextBlock` can contain multiple `Inline`s. Your markup won't even compile as `TextBlock` cannot contain a `StackPanel`.

Comment: (just to put this into context for anyone reading, I originally suggested having multiple objects in the `TextBlock`'s `Content` property could cause the exception, but didn't realise it accepts multiple `Inline` controls)!

Comment: This is suppose to be for windows phone

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that this is a windows Phone project

Comment: Cool. In that case, I'd still try updating your event handler to use the `MouseEventArgs` class to see if you encounter the same exception. My WPF project actually wouldn't compile if I used the wrong method signature, but I'm not sure if the Windows Phone compiler behaves in the same way.

Comment: Thanks alot James for you assitance. You the bomb

Comment: No problem buddy, any chance you could upvote and accept my answer please? Thank you :)

Comment: @user3302974 If you found this as answer, you should accept this as answer by clicking the tick mark instead of re-posting it again as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
void MouseEnter_Agent(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
```

The signature of the handler is wrong. Replace it with:

```
void MouseEnter_Agent(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
```